# Crear URLS amigables con htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

Estoy creando una pagina web dinámica en la cual se carga cierta información mediante una variable $_GET. y las url me quedan del tipo

```
  https://www.dominio.com/deals/deals.php?sdeal_id=483&name=nombre-producto
```

donde la variable **`deal_id`** es la ID de mi producto y con esto muestro la info en la pagina haciendo una consulta mysql, como el nombre,precio,etc y todo bien en esta parte. La cosa es que leí que utilizando el archivo **`htaccess`** puedo cambiar la url para hacerla mas amigable a los buscadores por un tema de SEO y colocarla de tipo :

```
 https://www.dominio.com/deals/445/nombre-articulo
```

He intentado varias expresiones regulares y no logro los resultados deseados ya que la url no muestra cambios y se sigue mostrando igual aun después de incluir la expresión regular en el htaccess y seguramente es porque no se implementar los cambios,  he utilizado esta expresión

```
Rewriterule ^deals/(.+)/(.+)/ deals.php?sdeal_id=$1&name=$2
```

y tambien esta otra.

```
Rewriterule ^deals/(.+)/(.+)/ /deals/deals.php?sdeal_id=$1&name=$2
```

El directorio en el cual se encuentra el archivo deals.php esta en

```
       raiz/deals/deals.php
```

que estoy haciendo mal ?

log del servidor :

```
 File does not exist: /home2/encorado/public_html/index, referer: https://dominio.com/deals/deals.php?sdeal_id=406&name=lavado-profundo-mantenimiento-por-hasta-4-mobil-special-minera-un-lavado-profundo-en-auto-cristales-santa-m
```

uso esta funcion para redirigir mis url

```
          function tep_href_link($page = '', $parameters = '', $connection = 'SSL') {
if (!tep_not_null($page)) {
  die('<div><font color="#ff0000"><b>Error!</b></font><br><br><b>Unable to determine the page link!<div>');
}  

    if ($connection == 'NONSSL') {
$link = HTTP_SERVER . DIR_WS_HTTP;
   }elseif ($connection == 'SSL') {
ENABLE_SSL == true;
$link=HTTP_SERVER . DIR_WS_HTTPS;
$url = "https://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    }else{
die('<div><font color="#ff0000"><b>Error!</b></font><br><br><b>Unable to determine connection method on a link!<br><br>Known methods: NONSSL SSL</b></div>');
 }


if (tep_not_null($parameters)) {
  $link .= $page . '?' . tep_output_string($parameters);
  $separator = '&';
} else {
  $link .= $page;
  $separator = '?';
}

while ( (substr($link, -1) == '&') || (substr($link, -1) == '?') ) $link = substr($link, 0, -1);

return $link;
   }
```

entonces lo que hice para generar mi url es lo siguiente :

```
$nombre_oferta=urls_amigables($rsCitySubDeal['product_name']);

<a href="<?php echo tep_href_link('deals/deals.php', 'sdeal_id='.$rsCitySubDeal['product_id'].'&name='.$nombre_oferta);?>">
```

lo que me genera una url de tipo

```
   https://www.dominio.com/deals/deals.php?sdeal_id=483&name=nombre-producto
```

cabe destacar que la url funciona ya que me genera los datos que quiero.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70833/discussion-on-question-by-alvaro-santafe-crear-urls-amigables-con-htaccess).

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que tu proyecto tiene el siguiente esquema

```
 /raíz
└─┬ /deals
  └── deals.php
└── .htaccess
```

Tu .htaccess debe ser parecido al siguiente:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^deals/(.+)/(.+)    deals/deals.php?sdeal_id=$1&name=$2 [B]
</IfModule>
```

Recuerda que el flag [B] es importante si las referencias $1 y $2 contienen caracteres que deben encodearse con la notación %.

Comment: `.+` puede ser una fuente de problemas a futuro. Por ejemplo, con la URL `deals/a/b/c`, se estaría pasando `?sdeal_id=a/b&name=c`. Siempre conviene excluir a la barra, por ejemplo usando `[^/]+`.